# encode method used as shown in the image javasript

Tags: javascript, encode

what method is used to encode an array into the text as shown
i tried searching it online but couldn't find it .

```js
var initialize=['w5LCvAvCrSPCi8K6w4U=','L8KWT8KnQBnCok1w','w7Adw7hyw7XDgynDonrDo8KU','w71PwrLDl8Khw5bCkBrDr8Ot','MWfDrMORw55VB3M=','w7fDgMK0wpE=','VHjCssO6bG/CqsO9SywFw6NJ','wrI9M2Q7wonDmzA3F8KkwpfClcKx','GEs7wpJdwpFJwqw=','DEs7wohTwp5dwqUOQkTDgHYk','wotMw4DDg0gWw7rDnA==','DQBhSEU0bA4=','w6ZOw6krw6bDhcOtw6E=','XFHCnzrDvg4DwqrCiMKfX8OOwpbDvg==','HcKww77Do29hwpc=','wrLDsB7Cu8Ofw6EWwoBtO1XCpxQ4NGwkIg==','woHCkW3Dk8OawoPDrcOrCcOQKcK9','WHDCrcOrKVLDrMO0Xi8C','w6gEwrN3wqMJwoUNw5vDrcO8w4UtOA==','wqpPw5jCik3DhH8WXMON','wrfDlMOsOxjDn3JnwrHCvULCtcOa','Ky1Iw4EKwrYYaA==','wqbDsFnCpmM=','IGfDk8KAw5dtw44Z','w4/DgDvCjg==','GSzDg8OCNMK0DMOzwrXCsCk=','c1nCm8OhesKAZlg=','wqTDucKWchbDq1LDlg==','w6fCuBHCny3Cig==','woUsYMO7bMOQfHQ=','woMtcMO+YcOVbXTDnsOhOcON','KsKfwp5iO8OdwobChw==','CCfDpcO5BQ==','woHDkMOxJhnDkQ==','w4HCukZXIApOIQ==','wrLDhMKyaDjDjnPCk8KyWw==','OQvDi8Od','wqY7NVsqwpHCjjg=','Xl3CngjDpkk=','w4FMw7Itwrk=','asKpKCUP','CAvDg8OdccKrBsO0wr/CsC8=','wrrDiTbCncO7w4Asw6FzEQ==','wqALwpcHNsOuw5MWw7s=','bH7CtsKXX8KFYVglwqPCk041','XX5sRMO/wrnDjz/DkVBE','w7nDkzTCnQ3Dog==','w5B+w6U7b8OzU8K0','wqBsw6rDjyLDqHARTcOcwqw=','GxfCusOeeTtXwp8=','K8KbwoFResO1wprCkBkNwplXRks=','wqTDucKWawHDolXDgcKUcVY=','wrp8w75Zwp/CpGLDgw==','wrHDvcKJQVfDpknDlMKRcEA=','wqPDt0LCqmVoNMOZ','wpTDucKLSA==','w4/CjcO+wrZIEA==','w5XDkMO/wonCqsOaw5fDk8K6wqN+','w6DDnsK6wpExG0LCgybDlMORYcOpw5XCqQ==','OsKSVcKQWwbCollydcKwwpNGw5YcwoZlwr4=','wqzDtBLChMOTw7gOw4U=','wrTDlMOrFBfDkCdD','w7piwpvCuMKcw6rConvDkMOFwqrCuTdqC8OyHMOPFcKGw7tIXlAHw4LCijfDpMKDd1HDgGDCusKH','w5nDlz3CkBHDuwhxwrvDiMOQw657LxVO','Ql5eRsK+wprDnDw=','wqUsIHo=','woZJw4PCr0gZw7DDhcOSw75Zw7thw4fDlsOMcsOI','w6F2wpXCuMKJw6zCoDfDhg==','wozClG7CoMOXwofDpsO7FcOtZ8KEUVgUKMOqEQ==','wqh9w65cwpLCoXPDg8OIGsKZw6o=','Bk83wq1RwohRw6kMT0vDnXw7wqPDtA7Chg==','w5TClnVJFUZ0IkDCtwY0','wpDCh8KMworCkWU=','Ckorwohdwp9ZwqU=','wqgwN2g5wonCni8=','wq7Co8KkwrrDnkfDusOsNE/DjQ==','wrAoesOJYsOR','wpnDvQnCvcOA','wqPCiMKWwofDk0nDtcOn','wr4PwpRxNsOsw4Ef','w67Cs37Cl8ORJsKKFWNubsKCXsK8wpDDssKzNg==','GCA5wqPDhg/CslHCuzLCqmh+Cw==','wqA6JUEqwp/CnjE=','GxfCusOedDZYwp/DlFg9','wqY0fhrCjcOTSMK/w5PCosO4FMKQTMOeZyzCmQ==','UlNPccKrw5jDrjzDlmBDABwKw4NDwrg=','JEvDn8OPw6sZPXB+McKPaw==','ZgYww7XCgMKWUMOvZcOmdWE=','P8K7w6jDgmZrwodBwpUyaMOo','wrnDrUbCpnl7','w4HDk8K7woIJFw==','wqsxfWnCgMOXQ8Kvw4/Cn8K2LQ==','wpPDrsKDUxLDv1fDn8KSfEc=','Zl3ChMOSO8Koek8jwrTCjkg0LA==','dl5eRsK+wprDnDw=','SsOnasOWw7fDoMOcw4kaYcO4wqjDsQw=','w7LDlsKxwqoHGEvChA==','c1nCm8OlfsKNf3IgwrHCiUQv','wo4LTcKNScOVe3TDj8OcPsOWaA==','HiEpwqbDiwrCo1E=','NGfDk8KAw5dtw44Z','wrt8w61mwo3CvHLDlMO5MsKbw7JFwr3CnMOO','wrludlIAw73Dl8Kt','OmPDv8Knw55UHWN2NsOKUlfCp3o4BQA=','wrM7JmQ4wonCni8VEsKtw5vClcKpw6ws','wqXCg8KWwr3CinrDtcOkIA==','w5fCpAnDsiohbMKWwqzCswEpwpnDs8OwwrDDnTB0worDn8OwCMOgwpTCssKjwpcJcsOcw751WlHDmQ==','UcO1TMOdw6zDpsOqw5UvdsOlwq/DoA==','cw0zw4HCgMKafMOlY8OEfmw=','wrHDvcKJQVfDg07DgcKYdkfDtWzCig==','MmzDk8K/wptAw5IR','wpHCl8KQwpo=','w5doJAfDkcKDGsO3woDDq8OlZMOMCcKKN2TDiVNOX8OwwoUmJRwwKMKAB0V5wrFGw7t3','OQzDgFFSwoHCtlRiwrvDnA==','wrVow7XDvGPDjmwA','w6XCs23Cm8KcF8KOR1RsdMKPXsK/','wrUowrkHGMOmw5IJw7sg','wo3DsAjCtsOdw7k=','wpPCgXvDqcOYwo0=','DjXDvnlywqU=','wqw0cl/DjMOxQcKsw47Cs8Ks','w6pywoXDscKbw7bCoinDoMOHwrTCvCV/UsK5','Xl3CngrDuTIUwqrCiMK3UsOMwpI=','bzE9wpRXBQ3DrB3CmcKv','w5wmw6pUw77DsC/DpXfDr8KFCmYFwrTDgw==','w5XDnsK6wokU','FcO0XMOfw6DDpQfCoUMi','wr46fl3CgMObb8Klw4nCvcK9IA==','LxfCv8OfOzo=','wq7Dq1XCuA==','CT3DtH51wq3CgR8Nw4DCunNeVMO2wo/CrXPCkzTCssOTEHk1wpxSw6prwpXDkA==','MmbDg8KVw55kw5gXwq8Nwp4=','WlDCjz/DswsSwqo=','wqzDuF/CqjdYOMOZw7TDrUh9w4vCoA==','wq1udlIAw73Dl8Kt','SsKkLC9dJgwJZ1oA','wqvDvVDCg3Z+NMOH','wq0bB1k=','w7lzwobDi8KEw6vCoz7DkcOvwrbCpA==','w5pSJMOsKsOuDw==','bH7CtsKXUcKFZ0kjwqU=','wqbDnHLCmzdTN8ONw6LDq0g=','wo7Cj8Oow5tbRxPDlTvCo8KFKMKgwo3DpsOAwqvDtF93w63DuVPCh8O8GcOwwpPDh2TDuS/CpEfDvcK8','IcO0XMOtw63DowvCpUQcw6DDtV4=','w6TCt3LCqMOdP8KSUA==','CMOMB21IwqlJYg==','DMK+w6LDtWVv','P0DDvsO2w7xow48IwqgQ','wplNw5DDg2stw5DDlsOaw7kcw4I=','SsKkLC9dIwMbYFoG','TXTCssOYaHHDv8O3','w4F4wpfDrMKdw6DConXDgMOJwrXDvzd3UsK9DMOIHsKTwro=','KcKXX8KnWALCr0ZlHMKtwoI=','woBhw67DhXA=','wr9vZlcNw7jDhsKtEjs8AQ==','w790KcKQMMKBNCzCkcKVasKEO1wmEzLCosKcwrLCjsKmMsOkw5JIPDLDmMK7bcONw4rDvsOYQQ==','PcOIHV9Gwqg=','DhPCpcO9NTxTwrfDnls9woHClQ==','w6TCt3LCrcOIIcKOW1Y=','c0jCncOedcKL','E8OiTcOMw6DDsAPCpQo=','wr/Ds8OGYjLDlSBDwr/Cpl7CtMOA','wrjDtBLChMOTw7gOw4U=','TlDCjz/DswsSwqo=','w5TCvlVkYSdVME/DqSIpwpA=','wrDCg8KFwofCjXzDucO4BEvDlW/Di07CiDA=','EidMPms+fxhCRg==','w6pJw7MrwqbDscOpwqzCojDCqWpIJ8KubxJL','w7DCjcOkwoddFHct','PQB8cg==','RcO1ScOcwqPDgcOQw4QvZ8O+','dzQuw7deDgnDqxo=','w6pewqXDkMK8wqLCiD3DhcOVwr3CpA==','FC0zwpnDhxPCuxTCmxXCqGNwEsO5YzHCtw==','cw0zw57CjcKRfcOs','wrnDvEDCmXZwJMOO','wpt4w6RrwpHCpQ==','wofCkH3DjMOZwonDqMOiK8O1JsKwXUQ=','NGfDk8Kaw5liw5oQwp0OwofDh2PCvw==','HcOMFFJawrFZdTzDqsKVHsOHwpYGwrw=','wo1Nw5DDmUgYw6rDlQ==','w4J1w6UEI8OeT8K8','w7R2woXCuMKJw6/CqC7DjcOSw7jCnSZmWMK/GsOK','w7R2woXCuMKJw6/CqC7DjcOSw7jCnS5wWMK/GsOK','L8O/XsObw7zDpQvCsg==','bzstwr4SIQfDqg==','Ghd0aQ==','dFXCjMOceMKDZlMy','w75SOcOQ','w6/Cs2HDnsOdPsKIQF97IMKrWMK/wpDDpcKjKQ==','EcO0RMOdw6HDvAvDrAo=','wrPDkz/DssO4w70Pw5RaKA==','w4QKw7lDw7PDhyfDrA==','HyU2wpXCigfCuFPCpRHCtQ==','wplcw5bDpkcT','w79ywpbDjcKbw6fCtTXDgsOLwr0=','TX3CqcO5XnzDpsO5DQAfw7JJZyA=','w6t7wo3Dr8K/w6PCqzDCg8OswrHCpDN7Qw==','wotMw4DDnEUdw7vDlcOOw4MXw4I=','w7DCt3LCqMOdP8KSUA==','MyJLwohIwpEXdsOww7o=','IWPDgMKzwpZAw5UIwqRPwqfDl2s=','KsOwT8Kew6/DvAHCtUQ7wqnDglpDw7EbwoAd','w5cVw7New68=','QsO6VsOQwq7DisOQw50=','wqTDsMKNUyDDpkvDmA==','ZHlgw43Cl1vDqwnDtEnDuzoiQsKtJGnDuDXCsn3ClU7CmC8rw5rCu8KHZMOZX8Ohw5jDljI=','YAgww7fDjMKydsO0eMKgUXHDsA==','w5XCukZXIApOIQ==','wr4PwpRyJMOlw4YUw785aQ==','wqQGEUICwqnCrBwaOA==','O8KWT8KiVQfCvkY=','LUIgwqtO','w67Cu2jCl8ORJsKKFWNubsKCXsK8wpDDssKzNg==','wqs3NXkuwo/DmzIwFcKyw5LCgw==','GCJSw4xIwpo='];
```

Comment: Please paste the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like binary data encoded as base64.

Comment: what makes you think it is a readable string that was encoded?